# How can I restrict a LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

What I would like to do is to find the first or default value of the role Name given the Id.

Here is the LINQ I tried:

```
var roleId = await db.AspNetRoles
                     .Select(r => r.Id)
                     .Where(r => r.)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is my class:

I have this class in Entity Framework Asp.Net Identity

```
public AspNetRole()
{
    this.AspNetUsers = new List<AspNetUser>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
```

When I look at what options I have after the r. I find that I cannot put in a name like r.Name

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Like this: `r => r.Id == 5`

Comment: What value type is the ID? Keeping in mind that your `where` statement is referring to `r` as an ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `Select` projects the source onto a new mapping, in this case only containing the int `Id`. From there on you'll be operating on an `IEnumerable<int>`, which don't have a `Name` property.

You could use:

```
.Select(r => new { r.Id, r.Name })
```

To project into an anonymous object only containing `Id` and `Name`.

Alternatively you can query first, then project:

```
await db.AspNetRoles
        .Where(r => r.Id == someId)
        .Select(r => r.Name)    
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or omit the projection (the `.Select()` call) entirely, but it all depends on what you want to do with the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to Change the order of the execution to

```
var roleId = await db.AspNetRoles
       .Where(r => r.Name = "your Name")
       .Select(r => r.Id)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

The Problem in your code is that you `Select` the `Id` which is of type `int`. Then when you call `Where` you have a list of `ints` available. If you swap `where` and `select` you first filter on `AspNetRoles` then `select` the int.

Comment: Good, but he wanted "Name from Id" -- you're giving him "Id from Name"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
var roleId = await db.AspNetRoles
                  .Where(r => r.Id == YourId)
                  .Select(x => x.Name)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or (If you are sure You have that Id):-

```
var roleId = await db.AspNetRoles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == YourId).Name;
```

But, Please note it will throw `Null Reference Exception` if no id matches :)

Comment: `==` for comparaison, not `=` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue makes perfect sense:). The problem is you are projecting before filtering. After the select you'll get a collection  of  ints. What you need to do is revers the   query like so :

```
  var roleId = await db.AspNetRoles
       .Where(r => r.Name=%smething%)
       .Select(r => r.Id)           
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order like so:

```
var roleId = await db.AspNetRoles
                      .Where(r => r.Id == 24)
                      .Select(s => s.Name)
                      .FirstOrDefault():
```

Answer (score 0):

You select r.Id in your select so the result only contains the Ids. You could also do it like  this:

```
var role = await db.AspNetRoles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Some name");
if (role != null)
{ 
    // more code about role.Id
}
```